# Is it possible to make onion Bhajis without a deep fryer?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I love these things. Is it possible to cook them in e.g. a frying pan if I keep turning them around? Or maybe by just filling up my crockpot a little way with oil (enough to cover the Bhajis but not so much it will spill over or spit everywhere)? Is that safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cook them in about 1" of oil in a steep sided frying pan or wok. Just turn them reasonably frequently to ensure even cooking.

If you're dubious about using a lot of hot oil, you can use less by making your bhajis a flat, patty shape and shallow frying.

Comment: would you be able to bake them?

Comment: Not really, you wouldn't get the same 'caramelisation'. You can reheat fried bhaajis in the oven though.

Comment: @dassouki You could but the mix would probably go dry before the outside crisped up. Still tasty but not perfect - a bit like baking scotch eggs instead of frying them.